# Embed an Iframe in a nexts js component

Tags: reactjs

Good morning all

I would like to create a react component with an iframe of the TradingView Widget: https://fr.tradingview.com/widget/ticker-tape/

But it does not work ...

Here is what I have on my page:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8H9G.png)

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class TradingView extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <iframe>
                <div className="tradingview-widget-container">
                    <div className="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
                    <script
                        type="text/javascript"
                        src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-ticker-tape.js"
                        async
                    >
                        {`
  "symbols": [
    {
      "proName": "FOREXCOM:SPXUSD",
      "title": "S&P 500"
    },
    {
      "proName": "FOREXCOM:NSXUSD",
      "title": "US 100"
    },
    {
      "proName": "FX_IDC:EURUSD",
      "title": "EUR/USD"
    },
    {
      "proName": "BITSTAMP:BTCUSD",
      "title": "Bitcoin"
    },
    {
      "proName": "BITSTAMP:ETHUSD",
      "title": "Ethereum"
    }
  ],
  "showSymbolLogo": true,
  "colorTheme": "light",
  "isTransparent": false,
  "displayMode": "adaptive",
  "locale": "fr"
  `}
                    </script>
                </div>
            </iframe>
        );
    }
}

export default TradingView;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/0.14.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline frames are used to embed another document within the current HTML document. You simply set the src attribute of the iframe to the URL you wish to embed. One gotcha I did note in Nextjs with elements under an iframe (as you have done) is that it causes a hydration error. Often iframe snippets such as the itch.io embed will give a fallback <a> link for browsers that don't support iframes.

Anyway, looking at the page you linked - you don't want an iframe for this embed. You simply need to create a component such as the below, using the Script component - I haven't tested it but it should get you on track:

```
    import Script from 'next/script'
       
    export default function TradingView() {
          return (
            <>
      <div className="tradingview-widget-container">
                    <div className="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
              <Script src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-ticker-tape.js">
{`
  "symbols": [
    {
      "proName": "FOREXCOM:SPXUSD",
      "title": "S&P 500"
    },
    {
      "proName": "FOREXCOM:NSXUSD",
      "title": "US 100"
    },
    {
      "proName": "FX_IDC:EURUSD",
      "title": "EUR/USD"
    },
    {
      "proName": "BITSTAMP:BTCUSD",
      "title": "Bitcoin"
    },
    {
      "proName": "BITSTAMP:ETHUSD",
      "title": "Ethereum"
    }
  ],
  "showSymbolLogo": true,
  "colorTheme": "light",
  "isTransparent": false,
  "displayMode": "adaptive",
  "locale": "fr"
  `}
</Script>
              </div>
            </>
          )
        }
```